# Android Studio rewrites my local.properties

Tags: android, gradle

Every time I build my app my local.properties get all messed up. It replaces my signing information with (I guess) old signing information and then it duplicates the values.

For example if I have this:

```
sdk.dir=/home/asdw/Android/Sdk
releaseKeyAlias=alias1
releaseKeyPassword=pass1
releaseKeyFilePassword=filepass1
```

It turns it into

```
sdk.dir=/home/asdw/Android/Sdk
releaseKeyAlias=22312alias1
releaseKeyPassword=4124pass1
releaseKeyFilePassword=4243filepass1
releaseKeyAlias=22312alias1
releaseKeyPassword=4124pass1
releaseKeyFilePassword=4243filepass1
```

How does this happen? The values that it rewrites it with are not even present in the project. I was working fine until a few days ago.

EDIT: It is still happening. I have deleted .android folder, hoping there was something wrong, but it did not help.